# UICollectionView that is populated by an UIImagePickerControl button that is in a Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that is populated by a UIImagePickerControl button that is in a Cell, I want the cell with the button to display the whole time, but I can't seem to get it to display.
Here is my code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.project.screens count];
}

 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {



    Screen* screen = [self.project.screens objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    CollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.screen = screen;
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
    }else{

    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"ButtonCell";
    CollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate =self;
    return cell;
    }
}
```

What should the code in my if statement be, and how do I add the +1 to the

```
return [self.project.screens count];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, in

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//Number of elements + 1 for the button
return [self.project.screens count]+1;
}
```

and in

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 1) {

Screen* screen = [self.project.screens objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
CollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.screen = screen;
cell.delegate = self;
return cell;
}else{

static NSString* buttonCellIdentifier = @"ButtonCell";
CollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:buttonCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.delegate =self;
return cell;
}
}
```